# Puppet integrated with Apache but unable to start due ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, puppet

I have installed Puppet as per official documentation and I have got installed Ruby 1.8.7.

But via rvm I have installed ruby 2.3.3 and then installed rack and passenger gems with `gem install rack passenger` and installed `passenger-install-apache2-module` successfully.

I made changes accordingly to puppetmaster.conf and placed it in conf.d directory of httpd service.

After starting httpd service I have given as `puppet cert` and its showing below errors

```
[root@lab puppet-fundamentals-puppetmaster]# puppet cert
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (L
oadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/module.rb:3
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/files.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/scope.rb:6
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/methods.rb:2
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/ast/method_call.rb:2
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/ast.rb:115
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/parser.rb:11
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser.rb:4
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:282
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:12
        from /usr/bin/puppet:7:in `require'
```

I don't understand why Puppet still looking over ruby 1.8 even I did mention as in puppetmaster.conf

```
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/passenger-5.1.2
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
```

Is there any way I can tell Puppet to look over ruby-2.3.3 as default ruby for all its needs ?

```
[root@lab ~]# puppet --version
3.8.7
[root@lab ~]#

[root@lab ~]# ruby -v                                                      
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]                  

[root@lab ~]# rvm all ruby list                                            

rvm rubies                                                                 

=* ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe Puppet 3.8.7 supports Ruby 2.3, or even Ruby 2.2. Try upgrading to a supported/non-obsolete version of Puppet.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thank you

Comment: There are actually a few other things I could bring up here, but as I recall Puppet 3.x was targeted for Ruby 1.9, maybe 2.0, and unlikely 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a wrapper see https://rvm.io/deployment/god

```
rvm wrapper ruby@gemset [scope] [binary-name]
```

Comment: so for my case how should I mention ? something like 

rvm wrapper ruby@gemset bootup puppet or bootup httpd ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `PassengerRuby` instead of `PassengerDefaultRuby`